# Python generating invitation link (pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

for those who work with telebot (pyTelegramBotApi) question: How to program telegram bot after the target action automatically generate an invitation link to a private group (and that the limit of joins was 1). and send this link to the user

Really need help, I am struggling all day. I will be very grateful for help

Answer (score 0):

Try using **exportChatInviteLink()** method. ([documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#exportchatinvitelink))

Also note that `any previously generated link is revoked`.